# React - passing props, wrong setup in navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying different ways to pass props between files. I am very new to react and very bad at it so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or the different ways of sending it. Either way, it works between 'main' and 'favplaces' but not between login and main, which makes me think it has something to do with how App is set up. If I log the params that I got from Login in main then I'm getting either undefined or the app is crashing saying "undefined is not an object".

App:

```
const mainOptions = SwitchNavigator({
  main : Main,
  favPlaces : favPlaces,

})
const introStack = StackNavigator({
  logIn : LogIn,
  register : Register
})

const SwNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  login : introStack,
  main : mainOptions

})
```

Login:

```
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            username: "",
            password:"",

        }
        this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
        this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
      }
     {......}
  signIn(){
        console.log("username", this.state.username)

        this.navigate({
    routeName: 'main',
    key: 'main',
    params: {
       username: this.state.username
    }
 });
  }
```

Main:

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
        this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    }
 handleClickFavourite = () => {
   console.log(this.state.latitude)
   this.navigate({
   routeName: 'favPlaces',
   key: 'favPlaces',
   params: {
      latitude: this.state.latitude
   }
});
```

}

favPlace:

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
        this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
      }

   render()
      console.log("1", this.props.navigation.state.params.latitude);
      console.log("2", this.params.latitude);
```

both of these logs work.

Comment: which library are you using to navigate?

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal looks like react navigation

Comment: I am using react-navigation. import { SwitchNavigator,TabNavigator, StackNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work. I removed the mainOptions navigator and changed the navigators to this:

```
const introStack = StackNavigator({
  loggingIn : LoggingIn,
  register : Register
})

const SwNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  //login : introStack,
  loggingIn : introStack,
  main : Main,
  favPlaces : favPlaces,
  register : Register

})
```